# How can I make breadcrumbs from a array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, breadcrumbs

This is the sample array

```
Array
    (
        [note] => Array
            (
                [to] => Array
                    (
                        [user] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => First User
                            )
    
                        [abc] => 123
                        [lmn] => 4582
                    )
    
                [from] => Jani
                [heading] => Reminder
                [body] => Array
                    (
                        [abc] => 123
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

**I want the following output from the above array.**

note > to > user > name

note > to > abc

note > to > lmn

note > from

note > heading

note > body > abc

Comment: You might want to consider an existing package such as [Laravel Breadcrumbs](https://github.com/diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs) as it is likely to provide functionality you'll want/require (such as linking to routes etc.).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is via a recursive function:

```
function breadcrumb($array) {
    $output = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach (breadcrumb($value) as $breadcrumb) {
                $output[] = $key . ' > ' . $breadcrumb;
            }
        } else {
            $output[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

[Try it online.](https://3v4l.org/VRmCA)

Comment: I was just about to paste the same answer, but you beat me.